# Замена в строке регулярным выражением со скобочной группой

Tags: javascript

Необходимо в строке, которая удовлетворяет регулярному выражению заменить только содержимое выделенное в "запоминающие скобки".

```
const name = 'Jimmy';

let str = '[I am name]';

str = str.replace(/\[[^.]*\b(name)\b[^.]*\]/, name); //?????
//желаемый результат [I am Jimmy]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше перестроить регулярное выражение так:

```js
const name = 'Jimmy';
let str = '[I am name]';
str = str.replace(/(?<=\[[^.]*\b)name(?=\b[^.]*\])/, name);
console.log(str)
```

https://regex101.com/r/oCYeOy/1

или так:

```js
const name = 'Jimmy';
let str = '[I am name]';
str = str.replace(/(\[[^.]*\b)name(\b[^.]*\])/, `$1${name}$2`);
console.log(str)
```

https://regex101.com/r/1djLGr/1

Comment: Спасибо. Второй вариант идеально подходит.